# bootstrap less makes page flash before loading content?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a site on local host using php,bootstrap , html , jquery everything was working fine until i added bootstrap less its still working but now if i refresh the page or go another page its like a flash before the page loads like it shows a blank screen and then loads the content, before i added less everything was cool it loaded just like any other site now its like a delay , anything that can help me with this issue?

when i use regular twitter bootstrap the page loads fine its just with bootstrap less

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style_template.css?v=2" type='text/css'>
<link href="../bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less" rel="stylesheet/less">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://js.pusher.com/3.0/pusher.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../bootstrap/js/less.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript">

  </script>
```

Comment: Ive never seen someone load .less in the browser... You should be serving the compiled css.

Comment: sorry im not understanding i just learned about bootstrap less through a youtube video and just followed instructions as to how to load it  , can you eplain better what you are trying to say

Comment: nevermind i did figure it out yes thats the reason why , because  i wasnt using a compiled css,thanks